# Finding the symmetric difference in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function that can take an indefinite number of arrays containing integer numbers and it should return 1 array which is the accumulative symmetrical difference between those arrays. Only two arrays are compared at a time. So `[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2], [1, 5, 3]`  would first result in `[1, 4]`, (comparing the first two arrays), which is then compared to the third and the final result is `[4, 5, 3]`. I created a loop that does that for the first two arrays, but I don't know how to turn it into an actual loop that performs the same operation on each step. For some reason using `arr[i]` and `arr[i + 1]` throws an error. Here's my code so far.

```js
function test(...arr) {
    let accumulator;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let common = arr[0].filter(a => arr[1].includes(a))
        let arr0 = arr[0].filter(a => !common.includes(a))
        let arr1 = arr[1].filter(a => !common.includes(a))
        let merged = [...arr0, ...arr1]
        accumulator = merged
    }
    return accumulator
}

console.log(test([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2], [1, 5, 3]))
```

Here `accumulator` is `[1, 4]`, so at this point the entire operation needs to be performed with the next array and the accumulator, which is where I'm stuck at.

Comment: _"For some reason using arr[i] and arr[i + 1] throws an error."_ You're iterating with `i` from `0` to `arr.length - 1`. `arr[i + 1]` is `arr[arr.length]` in the last iteration. It's out of bounds. You could change the loop condition to `i < arr.length - 1`.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating with `i` from `0` to `arr.length - 1`. `arr[i + 1]` is `arr[arr.length]` in the last iteration. It's out of bounds. You could change the loop condition to `i < arr.length - 1`.

Example:

```js
function test(...arr) {
    let accumulator;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        let common = arr[i].filter(a => arr[i + 1].includes(a))
        let arr0 = arr[i].filter(a => !common.includes(a))
        let arr1 = arr[i + 1].filter(a => !common.includes(a))
        let merged = [...arr0, ...arr1]
        accumulator = merged
    }
    return accumulator
}

console.log(test([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2], [1, 5, 3]))
```

Comment: I just did that and it works, thank you